# Bootstrap responsive layout - 2x100% width containers

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I desinged [my personal webpage](http://tybin.byethost3.com)  in non-responsive way, it's shaped to be properly displayed `@1920x1080` screen. Now, I want it to be responsive, so I began my adventure with Bootstrap. I know that columns must sum to 12, but my webpage has it content in 2 divs, **100% wide each** (visit my website and scroll to the right to see what I'm talking about).

My question is - how to port that layout to my responsive project? Is there any way to put 2 `container-fluid` divs in one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a wrapper, give it `200vw` width and `display: flex`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 200vw;
  display: flex;
}
.container-fluid {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgray
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        First
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Second
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or `display: inline-block`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container-fluid {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        First
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Second
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1st solution suits my needs well, thanks for the effort #LGSon <3

Answer (score 0):

The row must be in container-fluid and not the opposite. To create two div 100% wide you can:

```
<section class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
            First div 100% width for all device
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
            Second div 100% width for all device
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This code also doesn't do what I need it to do, I guess you misunderstood me.